# How to install a package with a specific dependency version with poetry?

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging, python-poetry

One package mylib-a have a dependency mylib-b with version 1.0.0, but I have another package in my application called mylib-c that have the dependency mylib-b too, with version latest (2.0.0, for example).

How can I fix the version 1.0.0 of dependency mylib-b to my package mylib-c in pyproject.toml?

Comment: Short version: it is not possible. -- Can you provide a [mre]? Do you have control over those 3 libraries? Can you modify them? -- Typically if 2 libraries depend on 2 different version ranges of a 3rd library, then there exists no valid combination of those 3 libraries that can be installed, end of story. It might be possible to force-install things, but then what guarantees that it will actually work?